# Where do questions about printing go?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I would like to know some basic information about printing, like types of paper, ink, their differences. Are these kind of questions appropriate for the site? If not, could you suggest another resource?

Comment: Hello there! In general, site-rec questions are better ask on the big [Meta.SE]. Would you mind if it got moved there?

Comment: @tohecz I'm pretty sure nobody from TSE who will be puzzled on the legitimacy of printing questions will go on Meta Stack Exchange to check this. And this was my primary reason to ask the question, the site recommendation request was just in case there is some standard and widely accepted universal answer worth knowing. So move the question if there is a well-established policy on such transfers.

Comment: Sorry, what is TSE?

Comment: @tohecz: TSE = TeX.SE.

Answer (score 11):

My suggestion would be to try [GraphicDesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com). The following is taken from their [on-topic help page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (*emphasis* added to related on-topic category):

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> **Graphic Design** is for questions targeted toward design professionals, students, and enthusiasts.
>
> This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual communication
> - Web design
> - *Layout and printing*
> - Illustration
> - 3D graphics
> - Digital media
>     Examples: video, Adobe Flash
>
> but not about:
>
> - Simple "How to" questions
> - Brainstorming or idea gathering
> - Technical questions related to video editing software
> - Web site architecture and development
>     Examples: HTML that doesn't include CSS, server-side issues
> - Landscaping and architecture